# how to initialize all the base class objects from derived class using base keyword

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

The following code initializes the base class from derived class using 'base' keyword by calling the base class constructor from the derived class.

```
    class A
    {

        public int a;
        public int b;
        public A(int x, int y)
        {
            a = x;
            b = y;
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        int c;
        public B(int s, int n,int z)
            : base(s, n)
        {
            c = z;
        }
        public int add()
        {
            return a + b+c;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B b = new B(2, 3,5);
            Console.WriteLine(b.add());//the output is 10 OK


        }
    }
```

### Question

what happens if a derived class inherits from more than one base class.then how to initialize all the base classes from the derived class using base keyword(how to call the base class constructors).**

```
class A
    {

        public int a;
        public int b;
        public A(int x, int y)
        {
            a = x;
            b = y;
        }
    }
    class B:A
    {

        public int d;
        public int e;
        public B(int x, int y)
        {
            d = x;
            e = y;
        }
    }
    class C:B
    {


    }
```

then from class C how to initialize both the base classes using base keyword.

Comment: Imagine all the people, [compiling for themselves](https://dotnetfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

A class can only inherit from one base class.

If your base class inherits from some other base class, your base class will initialize its base class, just like any other class.

Comment: thanks for the comment.you mean i can't call the constructor of class A from class C?

Comment: @RR: Correct.  A constructor can only be called once, and each class _must_ initialize its base class.  Since `B` must call `A`'s ctor, `C` cannot also call it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, in .Net you can only inherit from one Class, however you can implement a large number of interfaces.  The difference and how to achieve an effect similar to inheriting from a number of classes is out of scope of this question.

In your example (using the previous code sample as a standard) you would have to do the following

```
class A
{

    public int a;
    public int b;
    public A(int x, int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
}
class B:A
{

    public int d;
    public int e;
    public B(int x, int y): base (x, y)
    {
        d = x;
        e = y;
    }
}
class C:B
{
    public C(int m, int n) : base(m, n)

}
```

This would in effect instantiate C, which then calls the constructor of B which then calls the constructor of A.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting from multiple classes is not allowed in .Net. (Cause that would lead to [Diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)). But implementing from multiple interface and multi level inheritance is allowed.

In first snippet first A's constructor is called followed by B's constructor.
In second snippet first A's constructor will be called, then B's followed by C's constructor.

Comment: yes i am not using multiple but multi level inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out like so in LINQPad:

[image]

Copy-pastable code below (note, will only be 'valid' in LinqPad, due to } in odd places - requirement of linqpad)

```
var test = new C(1, 2);
}

class A
{

    public int a;
    public int b;
    public A(int x, int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;

        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{

    public int d;
    public int e;
    public B(int x, int y) : base(x, y)
    {
        d = x;
        e = y;
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

class C : B
{

    public C(int x, int y) : base(x, y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
```